# Проверка на строку js

Tags: javascript

как сделать так, чтобы была проверка на то, что в url есть "?rid=1" например

Answer (score 4):

```js
let url_string = "http://localhost/test.php?rid=2"; //window.location.href
let url = new URL(url_string);
let rid = url.searchParams.get("rid");
console.log(rid);
```

дальше с переменной `rid` делаем что душе угодно